# New Open Source Project - Namespace and License

Tags: open-source, licensing

I am starting an open source project on GitHub and would like to use a community-approved package name pattern that is acceptable and want to use a license that's acceptable.

For the package name...I have a registered LLC that I have done the bulk of the work under, but not sure if it's "acceptable" to use my company name in the package for an open source project?

In my mind I have two options:

```
com.avalutions.projectname.*
```

or

```
projectname.*
```

Does one of these make more sense than the other?  Did I miss an option?

What is best practice if I have no other immediate intent for this library other than share it with the community?  If I decide to incorporate the project in a cost-based project in the future, can I/should I change my license at that point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use whatever you want though using a registered company name can help with avoiding conflicts down the line. As the developer you are able to release your code under any license or licenses that you want, you can add licenses at any time. It's your code. If your code contains input from anyone else you need to ensure that their license to you is compatible with the license you plan to use or, where it's direct contribution (i.e. not a component or library) then they need to agree to their code being released in that way. There are plenty of successful OS projects out there that you can use as a licensing template.

Comment: I've tried browsing some projects on GitHub, but haven't found any solid examples for licensing.  Do you have any suggestions for projects to look at?

Answer (score 0):

LLC or personal authorship: That depends who the author is and if the author can re-assign coypright. It can make sense that you want to use your project for marketing purposes for either yourself or the LLC. Decide that on your own.

As there is always one level above *projectname*, you should also think into that direction:

```
org.foundation.projectname.*
```

If you want to create some eco-system around it's probably better if you don't put your own company upfront - but keep it visible.

> What is best practice if I have no other immediate intent for this library other than share it with the community? If I decide to incorporate the project in a cost-based project in the future, can I/should I change my license at that point?

From a developers point of view, decide for what you want to go public. Just showcasing or actual development? If you go for development, go open. If you need to go closed in the future you need to get copyright / re-licensing rights for contributions you pick from other contributors.